# Trunking Problem

Tags: electrical

I have been trying to Trunk some Electrical wiring in my sitting room/living room, but the 14.4 V Draper Drill and Drill Bit that I have tried will only penetrate through the wall by about 1 inch/2.5 cm. This is not enough to put a plug in. I am certain that there is a thick layer of wood inside the wall behind the particular area that I am having problems with.

Would I require an 18 V Drill to drill a plug hole in this area or would I require an SDS?

Comment: That sounds strange. I used to use mikata 9.6v drill motors for years with a good battery the 14.4v should do ok. The higher voltage drills do tend to last longer but this may be partly the type of battery.  I currently use dewalt 20v and can drill 3 -4 Ea 1-1/4 inch holes through steel I beams 1/2" thick on 1 5AH battery. A good quality battery drill may be what you want or a new high capacity battery for your old drill.

Comment: What does "trunk some electrical" mean, and what's a "plug hole"? Anyway, I don't care how crappy your drill is. YOU'RE HITTING SOMETHING YOU SHOULDN'T BE (like a protector plate). Or maybe it *is* just a bad drill. Can you hold the chuck in your hand and keep it from spinning? If yes, then it, or its battery is garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Having drilled plenty of large, deep holes with a 12V drill, I'm going with

1. You are hitting something metal that is trying to keep you from drilling
   into something you should not drill into (electrical, plumbing, gas)
2. Your current drill or battery is old and tired and not working right.

My 12V drill got like that, it got new batteries and got better, the next time it got bad it was more expensive to get it new batteries again than to buy a new cordless drill, and it was retired.

Number 1 is a much more likely bet, in general, and certainly the more serious of the two.